# Diagnosing USB disconncet+reconnect

Tags: usb

I have two Oculus Rift CV1 sensors, both with USB3 active extension coords, that will randomly disconnect and reconnect, which causes a lot of lag when it happens and interferes with VR functionality. I've tried the usual fixes I've seen: turning off "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" for the devices and disabling "USB selective suspend setting". Neither helped.

I want to see why the devices are disconnecting, whether it's because of a lack of bandwidth, lack of power, interference, or some other reason. Is there a log in Windows 10 (or possibly Linux) that can provide that information?

---

Some more info about my particular setup, if it helps solve the underlying issue, though I (and other people googling this question) would like to know how to diagnose the disconnects in general:

- I have this issue both with the motherboard's built-in USB3 ports on the back as well as a PCI-e USB card I've recently purchased.
- No third-party drivers for the PCI-e card or active extensions; they use the built-in Windows 10 drivers.
- The reconnects don't happen when I disconnect the two sensors from the active extensions, while leaving the extensions, as well as a third sensor that does not need an extension, plugged into the computer.

Comment: Why do you think that your "active extenders" are any good? How long they are? How many repeaters/redrivers do they have?

Comment: @Ale..chenski They're these, but I'd like to know why they are disconnecting rather than just speculating https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0179MXKU8/

Comment: These are 5-meter cables. Per common experience with cable industry, no commercial (mass produced) cable can transmit USB 3.0 data over 5m reliably. That's why the USB 3.0 standard and USB-IF test/certification framework do NOT define USB3 cables to be longer than 3 meters. It is very likely that the 5-m cable segment in your particular extender is marginal in terms of signal integrity.Try a different model, preferably with active element in the middle of extender. Also, look for "retimer" instead of just "redriver", if you can find any.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I don't see any cables on Amazon or Newegg that are  <= 3m and have active repeating. I also don't see any results for retiming. Where do you find such cables?

Comment: I've plugged in the sensors directly to the computer with no extension cables and the disconnects are still happening, so its not the active repeaters. Again I would like information on how to _diagnose_ the issue, instead of speculation

Comment: Yes, there are Event Trace Logs in Windows, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-capture-a-usb-event-trace but it is very non-trivial. And very little useful info. You will see Xfer errors and recoveries, but you already know that they are there. You need to try a better computer perhaps.